# warning: implicit declaration of function - order of includes matter?

Tags: c, warnings, declaration, implicit

I have the following sample code snippet of code from a main.c which calls 3 functions, with 3 headers - which is giving me warnings for a reason unknown:

```js
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#include "header3.h"

int main()
{
  function1(); // this is from header1
  function2(); // this is from header2
  function3(); // this is from header 3
}
```

Basically, after using gcc, the functions 2 & 3 will produce the warning. However, after rearranging the code to something like this:

```js
#include "header3.h"
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
   

int main()
{
  function1(); // this is from header1
  function2(); // this is from header2
  function3(); // this is from header 3
}
```

It will then give me the warning that functions 1 & 2 are implicit. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We need to see the exact contents of the header files. You probably have an error in one/all of them (using the same include guard is my guess).

Comment: Such errors occur if a header does not correctly include dependent headers or uses obscure macros/conditional compilation. See [ask], provide a [mcve].

Comment: @kaylum here is one of the header files, the rest follow suit 


`#ifndef __REZON_FUNCTIONS__
#define __REZON_FUNCTIONS__

void function1();
#endif  `

Comment: No, please post in the question by clicking the "edit" link. Code is not readable in the comments. And please post *all* the headers. "rest follow suit" can mean anything - what you think you have done may be different to what I think you have done. And those *exact* header contents are key to this question. And please put the exact C code as well as clearly there is no function in the header called `function1`, etc.

Comment: the problem is that you are likely using the same macro in each include file, so that include file's contents are only getting defined once.  Put REZON_FUNCTIONS1 in header1.h, REZON_FUNCTIONS2 in header2.h and REZON_FUNCTIONS3 in header3.h

Comment: @kaylum sorry just didn't want to reveal too much of my code since its for a school project, got the solution however - thanks for the help

Comment: @bruceg this worked, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your include file 1 should look like this:

```
#ifndef __REZON_FUNCTIONS1__ 
#define __REZON_FUNCTIONS1__ 

#endif
```

The other two files should be similar with the macro name changed accordingly